# Python Expression Evaluator similar to the Jave Spring Framework Expression Evaluation

Tags: python, python-3.x

### Goal

I am looking for a Python alternative to [Jave Spring Framework Expression Evaluation](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/expressions.html). My understanding that it is similar to .NET LINQ.

The goal here is to bring an ability to define filters from a string that is stored in a database and 'query' the objects that are in the memory.

### Example

```
# The class structure I am dealing with
class Order():
    def __init__(self,var1,var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2

class Work():
    def __init__(self, orders):
        self.orders = orders # list of Orders

order1 = Order(var1 = 11, var2 = "type1")
order2 = Order(var1 = 22, var2 = "type2")
order3 = Order(var1 = 33, var2 = "type2")

work = Work([order1,order2,order3])
```

I want to be able to execute strings similar to

```
 "var1 > 25 & var2=='type2'"
 "var1 IN (11,22) & var2 IN ('type1' OR 'type2')"
```

### Details

- **Performance is important**, I will need to execute tens of millions of these strings at a time
- **Do not want to use python eval()** because the evaluation strings will be open to a general audience and I don't want to allow any python code execution
- **Need rich syntax** to allow execution of complex queries. Something like [Spring Framework Expression Evaluation](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/expressions.html) but in Python or [YAQL](https://yaql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) but on custom objects in memory
- Thinking of the possibility to use [jQuery](https://querybuilder.js.org/#installation) to build the strings

Thank you very much for your thoughts and suggestions